# CommunicationException when importing Acumatica TaxCategory

Tags: acumatica

Trying to import/set a `Tax` to `TaxCategory` connection via a `TaxCategoryTaxDetail`.

```
var categoryDetails = new TaxCategoryTaxDetail
{
    TaxID = new StringValue {Value = "MYTAXID"},
    TaxCategory =  new StringValue {Value = "TAXABLE"},
};

var category = new TaxCategory
{
    TaxCategoryID = new StringValue {Value = "TAXABLE"},
    Details = new[] {categoryDetails}
};

_client.Put(category);
```

Calling `Put` throws:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (6553600) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

Endpoint version: 17.200.001
Acumatica version: 18.107.0022
Client app is in Visual Studio 2017 using the wsdl endpoint.

The `categoryDetails` payload is tiny compared to some other working calls I am using.

`categoryDetails` are saved in Acumatica correctly though. It seems as if Put is doing the update, then returning the actual category from the server back to the client. The category in Acumatica contains thousands of related Tax records. I do not want or need this. I'd rather it be a fire and forget update.

I could `catch` the exception and continue on but it is extremely slow waiting for exception to throw. And I feel I am just doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned data length exceed **MaxReceivedMessageSize** binding property.

You can increase the limit in 'app.config' file:

```
<binding name="DefaultSoap" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

or directly in the soap client constructor:

```
using (soapClient = new DefaultSoapClient(new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    AllowCookies = true,
    Name = "DefaultSoap",
    MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    Security = new BasicHttpSecurity() { Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport }
},
new EndpointAddress(url)))
{
}
```

In the webservice call you can also specify the return behavior:

```
ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.None
```

Comment: `ReturnBehavior.None` was what I was looking for. I knew it was something fundamental I was missing.